# No funciona implementation ':prueba' para librerias creadas en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Android studio no me permite usar otros módulos o librerías creadas dentro del mismo proyecto ni importadas  el error es :ERROR: Failed to resolve: :prueba: Affected Modules: app.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation ':prueba'
}
```

Este es el gradle de la libreria:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

El ejemplo lo pongo con una librería llamada prueba creada asi File/new/new module/ android library
pero no solo es esta la librería que no me funciona, el problema se me presenta con cualquier proyecto cualquier librería alguien sabe como solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 0):

No parece en realidad una dependencia local, elimina esa entrada ya que en realidad no es una dependencia local o que puedas descargar, elimina la referencia dentro de tu `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //implementation ':prueba'

}
```

Si es que existe el proyecto en realidad debes agregarlo de esta forma

```
    implementation project(":prueba")
```

---

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(":prueba")

}
```

Revisa la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-types)-

Answer (score 0):

Realmente estaba haciendo las cosas mal se debería incluir de esta forma:

```
 implementation project(path: ':prueba')
```

Comment: Trataste como comento en mi respuesta:  implementation project(":prueba") ?